# Envelope created as Draft

Tags: docusignapi

When i create an envelope using the eSignature REST API, the envelope is created as Draft in Docusign and with no content, as below:

[Docusign draft](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p9nfJ.png)

[Envelope details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lEbI2.png)

But, if i copy the body (json) and paste in postman and if i try to create, usign the DocuSign Rest API Collection, the envelope is created properly and docusign start the worflow automatically.

[Postman Envelope creation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CjRHY.png)

What i'm doing wrong? There any configuration which i need to setup? Any or suggestion?

Thanks in advance,

Luis Franco

Comment: The code is in AL (Dynamics 365 BC programming language). The code is the following: [Request](https://imgur.com/a/YmV7f78) and the request content ( json body) is [Request Body](https://imgur.com/DmmfDWg) When the API is called i get a success response and in the response body i can find the envelopeId returned from the API. If i go to the DocuSing and complete the Envelope, the system start to send the email and from the 365 BC i can get the new status and download PDF when the document is signed.

Comment: I don't see your JSON. I suspect that the various elements like documents are recipients were not correctly attached to the request body by your builder code. Can you find the JSON that is being sent and just paste the JSON into the question/

Comment: Hi Inbar,
Thanks for your reply.

Bellow you can find my Json without the base64document

{"emailSubject":"DocuSign API - Signature Request on Document","status":"sent","documents":[{"documentId":"1","name":"Contract of Services (CoS) 49.pdf","documentBase64":"...."}],"recipients":{"signers":[{"recipientId":"1","email":"luis.franco@xpto.co.uk","name":"Luis Franco","tabs":{"signHere":{"xPosition":300.0,"yPosition":500.0,"documentId":"1","pageNumber":"1"}}}]}}

Comment: When you send this JSON, do you get back and envelopeId?

Comment: Yes, i get back the envelopid.
Bellow and example of the response:

{"envelopeId":"2a40837f-5a93-467f-967a-eef6f31e90e2","uri":"/envelopes/2a40837f-5a93-467f-967a-eef6f31e90e2","statusDateTime":"2022-08-10T11:29:28.2770000Z","status":"created"}

Comment: I copy/pasted your JSON and added a valid PDF and got it working. I think the issue may be your account

Comment: Check if you got an email in luis.franco@xpto.co.uk

Comment: or maybe somehow the issue is the PDF itself, not sure

Comment: actually, let me me ask you something. you said postman works ok. So how do you do it the other way? using your code? what lang? do you use an SDK?

Comment: Hi @InbarGazit,

I developed some code in AL (Dynamics 365 BC programming language) to call the e-signature API. Is working for create an Envelope, get the envelope status, download signed PDF and void documents. The only problem (and the most important) i have is the creation of the envelope as draft despiste the API returns the envelopeID and the status = created.

I'll open a support ticket with DocuSign.

Comment: can you share the AL code?

Comment: The code is the following:  [Request](https://imgur.com/a/YmV7f78)  and the request content ( json body) is [Request Body](https://imgur.com/DmmfDWg)

Answer (score 0):

You need to open a support ticket with Docusign https://support.docusign.com/s/?language=en_US